# Java annotation to get the value of its field

Tags: java, annotations

Is it possible to pass the value of the parameter to the annotation?

For example:

```
@MyAnnot
final List<String> list;
```

I want the content of `list` to be passed to `MyAnnot`

Comment: If you want that the annotation-experts take a look at your question, make sure to add the corresponding **tag**.

Comment: You can get annotations and the fields they are attached to, and field values, but from the declaration of your question - no, you can't, because the value of the list is defined runtime, annotations, as language constructs, are being processed compile-time.

Comment: Passed how/when? Where are you trying to retrieve it?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What do you mean by pass the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible using standard Java.

An annotation is a form of class whose instances may be attached to various elements of a program; e.g. classes, methods, fields, parameters and so on.  For annotations with retention policy `RUNTIME`, an application use reflection to retrieve the annotations associated with a `Class`, `Method`, `Field` and so on.

The problem is that the annotations are associated with (effectively) syntactic elements, rather than instances of those elements.  So for example:

```
    public class Thing {
        @MyAnnot
        final List<String> list;
    }
```

We can use reflection to find the `Class` object for `Thing`, and the `Field` object for `list`.  And from there, we can get the `@MyAnnot` annotation associated with the `Field`.

However, the `Class`, `Field` and `@MyAnnot` instance are not associated with any particular instance of your `Thing` class.  If you wanted to get the value of `list` via your `@MyAnnot` annotation (somehow) it would need to know (somehow) which instance you were talking about.

The other interpretation of your question is that want (somehow) that each time your application assigns to a `Thing` object's `list` variable, that value assigned is also passed to the `@MyAnnot` annotation.  The JVM doesn't do that.  It is not standard behavior for annotations.  It would be theoretically possible to implement such a feature (with some heroic bytecode rewriting, for example) but I'm not aware of any examples.